# Can you translate a GetLastError() error code into the name of the #define?

Tags: winapi, error-code

[`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) returns a `DWORD`. Is there a Windows API function that translates this `DWORD` into a string, the name of the `#define`? E.g. for `123` it would return `"ERROR_INVALID_NAME"`. Here is a [list of system error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

[`FormatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) doesn't seem to do the job, but the [Microsoft Error Lookup Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/debug/system-error-code-lookup-tool) somehow prints the name of the `#define`.

Comment: In fact there's more than one match for 123 "ERROR_INVALID_NAME" and "DNS_ERROR_INVALID_NAME" just in winerror.h: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=123+AND+filename%3Awinerror.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without creating a database of such mappings yourself. Basically a `std::map<DWORD, std::wstring>`, `FormatMessage` only gets you the message text, not the `#define` (remember, `#define` tokens disappear very early in the source processing).

The Microsoft Error Lookup Tool contains the names of the `#define`'s and the message texts in the .exe. You can check it with a binary viewer.